# Nested Routing Links Angular 4

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

This is my **current setup**:

```
 - app (Folder)
  - app-routing.module.ts (File)
     - client (Folder)
         - client-routing.module.ts (File)
             - service (Folder)
                 - service-routing.module.ts (File)
                 - service1.componenent.ts (File)
                 - service2.componenent.ts (File)
```

So, right now if I use **router.navigateByUrl** inside **service1.componenet** I'll have to do it like this:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/client/service2');
```

I'll have to keep nesting routing-modules so knowing the **"parents"** of the route later on might be a problem, I wanted to know if there is a more **efficient solution** rather than copying the whole route, something like:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl( parentRoute + '/service2');
```

Where the parentRoute it's a compilation of the nested routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `ActivatedRoute` in the `service1component`.
Something like this:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
...
})
export class Service1Component {
 constructor(
   private _router:Router,
   private _route: ActivatedRoute
 ){}

 ...

  navigate(){
    this._router.navigate(['./service2'],{
      relativeTo: this._route
    });
  }
}
```